Visual Studio 2022 v17.11 to v17.12 Upgrade - Form Designer Issues
We have a very large WinForms solution (38 projects) that targets .NET 8.0 (Windows), and it worked just fine in VS 17.11.6 but as soon as we upgraded to v17.12 we can no longer open most Forms/Controls in the out-of-process form designer. (Multiple users)
We can compile the entire solution and run the application just fine.
We are able to open Forms/Controls that derive directly from Form or UserControl, but any that derive from subclasses of Form/UserControl fail with either the "The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed" or "Could not load file or assembly 'WinRT.Runtime, Version=2.1.0.0..." (we're not targeting WinRT.)
I did some digging and found that a new WinForms project targeting .NET 8.0 (Windows) worked just fine with the Form Designer.  I compared project files and found that is I removed the OS versioning from the target platform, ex. "net8.0-windows" instead of "net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0" I could then open the Form Designer.
After further trial and error, I found that if the project targeted windows 7 or 8, the designer would work fine, but anything newer and it would fail.
Has anyone else run into this?  And is there a way to fix it?
Currently, I'm rolling back to VS 17.11.6
Any help appreciated.

Is net8.0-windows a problem for your project ? We have also converted a hugh winforms project and we just kept that target platform. Is there a reason why you want to target a specific windows version ?

Thanks @GuidoG we migrated this larger project from  .NET Framework to .NET 6 a while back and I think at that time we probably selected to target the most current version of Windows because we weren't targeting 7 and there was no "default" or "none" option.  Changing all the projects to remove the versioning from the TargetFramework does seem to resolve the issue for us.

After some more experimentation I found that the issue was caused when updating to Visual Studio 2022 v17.11.6, but the release window was so short between that and v17.12 that I likely never tried to edit a Form/Control in the designer, so assumed it was v17.12 that caused it.
As we don't have a good reason to target a specific version of Windows, we have decided to alter the TargetFramework to be "net8.0-windows" for all our projects and that does seem to resolve the issue we are having with the Forms Designer.
However, I'm sure there are plenty of people out there with good reasons to be targeting a specific version that may also run afoul of this issue, so hopefully Microsoft will address it in an upcoming release.

I found a post online with an error very similar to yours (Could not load file or assembly 'WinRT.Runtime, Version=2.1.0.0) that also occurred when targeting net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0. In the post, the issue was caused by CommunityToolkit.Mvvm using the new Windows SDK projections after an update, while the application was still using an older version of the Windows SDK.
8.3.0 and WinForms throws Could not load file or assembly 'WinRT.Runtime' · Issue #927 
Exception on startup with version 8.3.0 · Issue #923 
Based on this, your issue probably is also caused by a mismatch between the Windows SDK version and the required version.
You can try adding the following to your .csproj file:
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.22621.56</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>
</PropertyGroup>


thank you for the suggestion, I did try it, but it made no difference. We ended up removing the version info from the TargetFramework for all projects and that seems to have resolved the issue for us.
